# Chrome content script does not load in about:blank page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am developing a Chrome extension which will load content script according to the following manifest:

```
"content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "js" : [  "scripts/namespace/namespace.js",
                "scripts/log/Logger.js"]
       "run_at" : "document_start",
       "all_frames" : true
     }
]
```

There is a mockup site whose HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=javascript>
    var test;

    function makewindow() {
        test=window.open('mywin');
        test.window.document.write("<html><body><A onclick=window.close(); href= > click Me to Close</A>");
        test.window.document.write(" ---- </body></html>");
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="" onclick="makewindow();return false;" >Click me to launch the external Window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If I click the A link and it will run `makewindow` function and pops up a new window.

The URL of new window is `about:blank`, and content script is not loaded in this new window.

How to load content script in this new window?

Comment: about:blank is a special case. Have a look at http://hsivonen.iki.fi/about-blank/

Comment: yeah, but is there any way to load content script in about:blank page?@thefrontender

Comment: You need to clarify: do you want to load scripts into about:blank or are you really just trying to open a new window and manipulate it without providing a URL?

Comment: I want to load content scripts into about:blank. @thefrontender

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** As of Chrome 37 (August 26, 2014), you can set [the `match_about_blank` flag<sup>Doc</sup>](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank) to `true` to fire for `about:blank` pages.

See [alib_15's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36329205) below.

---

---

**For Chrome prior to version 37:**

You cannot load a Chrome content script (or userscript) on `about:blank` pages.

This is because `about:` is not one of the "permitted schemes".  From [chrome extensions *Match Patterns*](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html):

> A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a **permitted scheme** (`http`, `https`, `file`, `ftp`, or `chrome-extension`)...

---

In this case, you *might* be better off hijacking `makewindow()`.

Comment: @alib_15, this was correct at the time of the question.  Updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Brock. I'm writing my 1st extension and this caught me out too. I think it catches out a lot of people. I suspected your answer was correct at the time of writing but I felt a little mischievous.

Answer (score 6):

In the manifest file, add a line:

```
"content_scripts" : [
{
  "matches" : [ "<all_urls>" ],
  "match_about_blank" : true,
  "js" : [  "scripts/namespace/namespace.js",
            "scripts/log/Logger.js"]
   "run_at" : "document_start",
   "all_frames" : true
 }
]
```