# Script or extension execution on a blank page and a new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using a mouse gestures extension on Chrome (crxMouse Chrome Gestures) that works everywhere but blank pages, new tab page and the chrome store. This behavior is the same with other mouse gesture extensions.

My question is, is there a way to enable this extension on a new tab and a blank page? (by a blank page I mean like the page that opens up when you download something for example)

Can I unpack the extension and change something in the `manifest.json` to enable this?

I ask here because the support for this extension on chrome store is non existent and there's no mail support.

Comment: Not much you can do about [webstore pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613371/chrome-extension-content-script-on-https-chrome-google-com-webstore) or [blank pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785641/chrome-content-script-does-not-load-in-aboutblank-page), or any non-permitted scheme like 'chrome://', for that matter. As for new tabs, i can't replicate, seems to be working fine..

Comment: Ah I see, I have a new tab extension, it doesn't work because it directs to a different new tab page than the default? @CViejo